# Mysql limit order by question

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

I have this query: `SELECT * FROM mash order by id asc limit 10`

but what i'm attempting to do is select the last 10 records inserted but order by id asc.

So say the data is: `13,4,4,5,6,78,4,23,21,1,1,2,3,4,5,65,6,7,3` and "3" was the last record inserted, how could i select `1,1,2,3,4,5,65,6,7,3` from it?

Comment: do you have a column with timestamp of recode insertion?

Comment: Such a query cannot be written unless you have a column that stores the insertion order in some way (an incrementing identifier or a timestamp?). The order in which rows were inserted is not stored anywhere automatically, so you can't ask the database to give you rows in that order without storing it yourself. It may *appear* that if you don't specify an order you get the data back in insertion order, but that's only a temporary artifact, and won't hold true in the long run.

Comment: yes, i do, but i'm doing some subtraction with the data, so i need it ordered a specific way

Comment: You need to tell us where that insertion order is stored if you want use to write you a query that's based on it!

Comment: Folks, do not assume that the data above is from the id column (he said select *).  @benhowdle89, it would be helpful if you could clarify this to clear up that confusion.

Comment: Hi, sorry i have id, steam, tstamp. I'm doing some subtraction math in a PHP while loop on the steam column. So i need the last 10 inserted but not order by desc as this will mess up the subtractions

Comment: So `tstamp` column stores the time when the row was inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best you ca do is

```
select * from (select * from mash order by creation desc limit 10) s order by s.id
```

Comment: Two minor edits and this is the correct answer (substituting whatever field stores the insertion order for `creation`): Drop the unmatched opening parentheses, and give the derived table an alias or it won't run

Comment: Assuming there is in fact a `creation` column.

Comment: this was the right answer thanks! sorry for not fully explaining my problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (select * from mash order by id desc limit 10) order by id
```

assuming ID is your monotonically increasing record of insertion (as it usually is).

Comment: But might not be. See multi-master replication setups for example. Relying on this property is not a good idea.